# Using Azure Multi-Tenant application without an Office 365 subscription to access users calendar information

Tags: api, rest, azure, office365, outlook-restapi

We have written a service application that reads Office 365 calendar information from multiple calendars in an organisation (tenant) and does some analysis against the entries. We use the Office 365 REST API for this.
We have multiple client organisations (tenants) that require this functionality so I have followed the steps in [@Matthias Leibmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3394032/matthias-leibmann) article here: [Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx)

We used a trial Azure account and a trial Office 365 subscription during development and everything works very well and we have been successfully accessing data for several tenants.
However, when I tried to set up the Multi-Tenant Application using our production Azure account and production Azure Active Directory (AAD) I realised that I can’t define the Application Permissions required for “Office 365 Exchange Online” in the “Permissions to other applications” section of the UI because our production AAD account isn't linked to an Office 365 account.
I assume we could sign up for a developer trial of Office 365 using our production azure account and this would allow us to set the required permissions, but I don’t know what will happen in 30 days when the office 365 trial expires.

Is there a way to define these required permissions without having an Office 365 account linked to our production AAD?
Is this just a tooling issue within the Azure front end or is there a technical reason that we need an Office 365 subscription of our own even though we’re always connecting to some other company’s Office 365 account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the way it works is you do need an Office 365 subscription, and a [Developer Subscription will do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment). I can check with our Azure folks about what would happen if you added a trial and then let it expire.

Comment: thanks @Jason Johnston it's the answer I was expecting but not the answer I was hoping for. I'd be great if you could check with the Azure folks about what will happen at the end of the trial period and let me know.

Comment: I can’t figure a way to connect a new developer subscription to an existing (pay as you go) Azure Active Directory. Obviously we could run it out of a completely separate AAD but it’d be preferable to run it from the existing production AAD. Can you assist with this at all?

Comment: Ok. The Azure folks said that if you use a trial and let it expire it should not cause the registration to stop working. I don't know if you can add a developer sub to a normal AAD just because developer subs are created as single-user tenants. I looked in the Office admin portal and didn't see a developer sub as an option to add. There is the option to add normal Office 365 plans though.

Comment: One thing you might try before adding a subscription is using the Visual Studio tooling to register your app. I don't have a non-O365 AAD to try this with, but I'm wondering if it might get you around the requirement. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15b85e6-69a7-4fdf-adda-a38066bb5155

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Jason Johnston As far as I can tell you can’t add a developer sub to a normal AAD, at least I can’t figure a way to do it. I gave your suggestion about using Visual Studio a try, but unfortunately it’ll only let you Sign In if your account has an Office 365 subscription associated with it. So it looks like we’re stuck at the moment.

Comment: I agree it doesn't look like you can. I've shared this information with the powers that be.

Comment: Thanks again @Jason Johnston Just to follow up, my Office 365 Trial Developer Subscription expired a few days ago, but our application continues to work, so that's a positive. Of course there's no way to re-configure any permissions the application might require in the future, or create new keys, or do any azure configuration what-so-ever, but for the short term things are working so lets call that a win.