# Office 365 Outlook Calendar : How to access multiple user's calendar in a single ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, calendar, exchange-server, office365

We are trying to implement a calendar portal (C# ASP.NET MVC) where one admin can see multiple outlook(or office 365) users calendar and see who is available. So multiple accounts should be accessed from one ASP.NET MVC application.

First question : Is it even possible? (may be because I had already seen post on stackoverflow : [EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars) )
Second question :  What would be the right approach?
Third question : Is there any project available from Microsoft or article? (I could find any good one)

I have had gone through [Using Azure Multi-Tenant application without an Office 365 subscription to access users calendar information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069788/using-azure-multi-tenant-application-without-an-office-365-subscription-to-acces) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kvDyl5HShA.

I have had also get connected with a single user's account via OAuth2. It was successful.

Currently, we have this subscription. If any more information required then please comment. Then I will add more description as per necessary.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to build Daemon or Service Apps using client credential grant flow as described in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/), the service app that requires admin consent, but is authorized to access any user's mailbox/calendar information in your Office 365 tenant. You could click [here](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2143) for sample web app that uses client credential flow to access Users, Mail, Calendar, Contacts in Office 365 via Rest APIs .

This [link](http://%20Using%20Azure%20Multi-Tenant%20application%20without%20an%20Office%20365%20subscription%20to%20access%20users%20calendar%20information) you provided needs to associate your Office 365 account with Azure AD to create and manage apps .If you can have an existing Microsoft Azure subscription, you can [associate your Office 365 for business subscription with it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#bk_AssociateExistingAzureSubscription) .Otherwise, you'll need to [create a new Azure subscription and associate it with your Office 365 account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#bk_AssociateNewAzureSubscription) in order to register and manage apps. For more details ,please read how to [set up your Office 365 development environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment).

Comment: Thank  you for your detailed answer +1